# How to retain values when browser back using useNavigate

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

How can I use useNavigate to retain values when I browser back?
I have written the following code, but state will not read in the previous page.

```
const backToPrePage = useCallback(() => {
    navigate(-1, { state: { userID: userID, currentState: currentState } });
  }, [navigate, currentState]);
```

If I specify the URL of the original page instead of the browser back, it works.

```
const backToPrePage = useCallback(() => {
    navigate("/prepage", { state: { userID: userID, currentState: currentState } });
  }, [navigate, currentState]);
```